# Converting LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE to int

Tags: c++, windows

I'm working with a C++ code base which contains some lines like the following:

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, MyThreadMethod, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

I would like to write the value of `MyThreadMethod` to debug output. (I suppose it's a hexadecimal address).
`MyThreadMethod` has the type `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`. I already have a method called `OutputDebugInt` which can write an `int` to debug output. When I to compile the line

```
OutputDebugInt(MyThreadMethod);
```

then the compiler issues the error

> cannot convert parameter 1 from `unsigned long (__stdcall *)(void *)` to `int`.

So is there a way to convert `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` to `int` (or something else which can be written to debug output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::basic_ostringstream<TCHAR> ss;
ss << static_cast<void*>(&MyThreadMethod);
::OutputDebugString(ss.str().c_str());
```

Converting to `int` is possible on 32-bit platforms, but not 64-bit platforms, so I'd stick with creating a string instead.